# Compute eccentricity and angular momentum vectors of a binary

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements

I having some trouble finding the direction vectors (in 3D) of the eccentricity and angular momentum of a binary. The issue is that the binary has only been described in Keplerian orbital elements and I know the: inclination with respect to the a reference direction (in this case the x-direction), argument of pericentre and longitude of ascending node and the semi-major axis. I am given the magnitude of the eccentricity and the angular momentum, but I need to find the direction of each vector which is what I am completely stuck with. Can someone please guide me on this?

Thanks!